# No weekends please

Tags: date-and-time

I need to get the `DateValue`s of the last 30 days (starting from yesterday, not today!) excluding saturdays  and sundays. I want that the dates are german time (GMT + 1). The only solution I have found so far is to download with `FinancialData` the share prices of a german company for the last 30 days,
 since stock exchanges are closed during weekends.

For example:

```
yesterday = Take[DateList @ Today, 3] /. {a__, b_} :> {a, b - 1}
```

> {2015, 3, 30}

```
FinancialData["F:VOW", {{2015, 2, 28}, yesterday}][[All, 1]]
```

(F:VOW is a german share) gives the wanted result:

> {{2015, 3, 2}, {2015, 3, 3}, {2015, 3, 4}, {2015, 3, 5}, {2015, 3,
>   6}, {2015, 3, 9}, {2015, 3, 10}, {2015, 3, 11}, {2015, 3,    12},
>   {2015, 3, 13}, {2015, 3, 16}, {2015, 3, 17}, {2015, 3,    18}, {2015,
>   3, 19}, {2015, 3, 20}, {2015, 3, 23}, {2015, 3,    24}, {2015, 3, 25},
>   {2015, 3, 26}, {2015, 3, 27}, {2015, 3, 30}}

But - because of the download of share prices which I don't need - my "solution" takes seconds and seconds.

Please speed this up for me

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how you can get the last 30 weekdays starting from yesterday:

```
days = DayRange[DayPlus[Yesterday, -30], Yesterday, "Weekday"]
```

To get `{y,m,d}` vectors, we might use

```
Take[#, 3] &@*DateList /@ days
```

Regarding the time zone, the only problem I can see would be that `Yesterday` will not produce the right result around midnight. To check this I used the [Spelunking](https://github.com/szhorvat/Spelunking) package, which told me that `Yesterday` is implemented as

```
Yesterday := DateObject[Take[DateList[], 3] - {0, 0, 1}]
```

`DateList` uses the time zone that is set on the computer you are using, so if your computer is set to the German time zone then you are alright. If not you can define a new function just like the one above but with `DateList[TimeZone -> 1]` instead.

Comment: great answer: It should be swedish or german time (gmt+1) only showing y,m,d

Comment: I think `Yesterday = DayPlus[DateList[], -1]` for v9?

Comment: @bobthechemist That looks right; I've also added another alternative to the post.

Comment: @eldo I think I've resolved the time zone issue now, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Yes,, you have,dear Pickett. Before I accept  tomorrow I would like to understand the `DayPlus`-function, which is new to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[DayPlus[DateList[TimeZone -> 2], #] & /@ 
Range[-30, -1], (! DayMatchQ[#, "Weekend"] &)]
```

I live in Germany TimeZone -> 2 is the correct Timezone for summertime and in winter i goes you have to take TimeZone-> 1

If you run the Kernel from Germany

```
 $TimeZone
```

should always have the correct value (Summer and Wintertime) so i suggest to leave this Option out.

Comment: Thank you too, sacratus,. You have - $TimeZone - solved my concern about different time zones:: My PC is in Berlin, so my time zone is Berlin.

Comment: @eldo np, from the docs of `$TimeTone`: 
`$TimeZone` *is set at the beginning of your Mathematica session to the time zone specified by your computer operating system.*
So you dont have to think about this ;-)